# Solving a series with this form without using induction or countdown method

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, summation

[image: Question]
Ok so i have to solve the question above and find the general term of this sequence without using the induction method or the countdown method.  So i want to calcul this with the geometric formula or arithmethic given :
[image: formula]

I thought this would be a summation of an arithmetic sequence but using the formula i don't get the answer.

I've tested the answer with wolframalpha entering  : y(0)=2,y(n)=2y(n-1)+3n-4

Using the geometric formula i get close to the answer but missing -3n, so i'm kinda lost. Could anyone help thanks !

Maybe it can't be solved with geometric or arithmetic formula and i'd have to use an other method ?

Answer (score 1):

Assume $a_n=b_n+pn+q$ therefore $$$$

therefore $$a_n=b_n+3n+2$$therefore $$a_{n}{=b_{n}+pn+q\\=2b_{n-1}+3n-4+pn+q\\=(3+p)n+q-4+2(a_{n-1}-pn+p-q)\\=2a_{n-1}+n(3-p)+2p-4-q}$$by defining $p=3$ and $q=2$ we obtain $$a_n=2a_{n-1}$$ and since $a_0=b_0+2=4$ we conclude that $a_n=2^{n+2}$ and$$b_n=2^{n+2}-3n-2$$

Comment: First, thank you for your answer, but i'm kinda unsure what made you define $a_n$  like that ? Also why did you replace it there in the $b_n$ thank you !

Comment: You're welcome. This is because a linear term like $3n-4$ strongly should have a linear source too (in some cases this is not possible). This made me think that $a_n=b_n+pn+q$  can be such that the representation of $a_{n+1}$ as a linear function of its priors, does not depend on $n$ (or any linear combination of n such as $3n-4$ in this case). By a simple calculation, I derived $p$ and $q$ and substituted. Also once you could simplify $b_n$ to $a_n$ you'd be better substitute it anywhere with $a_n$ to make your proof easier.

Comment: Wait, you used derivative to obtain $a_n$ ? not sure we saw that in class haha,  how would you obtain it without it ? I'm unsure. thanks !

Comment: I didn't say that! Derivation is not allowed in concrete mathematics.....

Comment: Then i'm not quite sure how you landed on $b_n$ $+3n +2$ hahaha

Comment: I added more details to clarify it. Hope it help now!

Comment: The thing that bug me is how do you find the + 2 for $a_n$ haha , also the recurrence formula given in the exemple isn't arithmetic or geometric right ?

Comment: Also in my head, i only see $a_n$ $=3n-4$  so i dont get how you arrive at $a_n$ $=b_n+3n+2$  i understand that you redefined $a_n$ by your first expression  but i dont get why you did or can do that

Answer (score 0):

Let $b_m=a_m+p+qm$

$3n-4=a_n-2a_{n-1}+p+qn-2(p+(q-1)n)$

Set $p-2p=-4$ and $2-q=3$ to find $a_n=2a_{n-1}=2^ra_{n-r}$

Comment: What i've done : $2(1-2^{n+1})/(1-2)$ which result in $2^{n+2}-2$ seems like i have the same answer as you but from wolframalpha, the answer should be : $b_n =-3n +2^{n+2} - 2$